# pdo fetchAll with htmlspecialchars - protect js injection

Tags: javascript, php, jsrender, htmlspecialchars

So my website will allow users to save `<script>alert("hey");</script>` to basically any field, and then when I render it, it'll display the alert, and it shouldn't. In reading about it, it sounds like you should use htmlspecialchars when you select and render the data.

I have an api layer where I select the data and return json, which then gets rendered with jsrender.

Here is an example of my query and api:

```
$return = ["list",[]];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `News`;"
if ($stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare($sql)) {
        if ($stmt->execute($param)) {
            $list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $return["list"] = $list ;
        }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $return);
```

My templates look something like:

```
<div class="card-header  py-1 px-2">
        {{:Comment}}
</div>
```

In my api, where would I put htmlspecialchars?

Comment: Are you allowing any HTML? If not, it makes sense to strip it out before saving. Otherwise, probably want to encode your content (again, when saving). Both can be done with filters: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php. There's also strip_tags, if you want to allow a subset of valid tags: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Be veryyy careful if you use `strip_tags`. That will mutilate scientific formulas, and other data with valid `<` and `>` symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be encoded at the place immediately before it gets rendered into HTML, and since you are not rendering it in PHP but actually in JavaScript, you should do it there (consistently).

(If you instead encoded it PHP-side, you would have to remember that this text is *only* intended for display, otherwise you'd end up with double-encoding as soon as you, for example, pass it to another API method.)

In JSRender there is the `{{>...}}` tag for that (instead of `{{:...}}`). For details, see its [docs](https://www.jsviews.com/#htmltag).

```html
<div class="card-header  py-1 px-2">
        {{>Comment}}
</div>
```